# Extending ggplot2: How to build a geom and stat?

Tags: r, ggplot2, proto, ggproto

I am in the early stages of learning how to extend `ggplot2`. I would like to create a custom `geom` and associated `stat`. My starting point was the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html). In addition, I have benefited from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156387/how-to-make-a-custom-ggplot2-geom-with-multiple-geometries) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52539301/creating-geom-stat-from-scratch). I'm trying to put together a template to teach myself and hopefully others.

Main question:

**Inside my function `calculate_shadows()` the needed parameter `params$anchor` is `NULL`. How can I access it?**

The goal described below is intended solely for learning how to create custom `stat` and `geom` functions, it's not a real goal: as you can see from the screenshots, I do know how to leverage the power of `ggplot2` to make the graphs.

1. The `geom` will read the data and for the supplied variables `("x", "y")` will plot (for want of a better word) `shadows`: a horizontal line `min(x)--max(x)` at the default `y=0` and a vertical line `min(y)--max(y)` at the default `x=0`. If an option is supplied, these "anchors" could be changed, e.g. if the user supplies `x = 35, y = 1`, the horizontal line would be drawn at the intercept `y = 1` while the vertical line would be drawn at the intercept `x = 35`. Usage:

   ```
   library(ggplot2)
   ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
       geom_point() +
       geom_shadows(x = 35, y = 1)
   ```

[image]

2. The `stat` will read the data and for the supplied variables `("x", "y")` will compute `shadows` according to the value of `stat`. For instance, by passing `stat = "identity"`, the shadows would be computed for the min and max of the data (as done by `geom_shadows`). But by passing `stat = "quartile"`, the shadows would be computed for first and third quartile. More generally, one could pass a function like `stats::quantile` with arguments `args = list(probs = c(0.10, 0.90), type = 6)`, to compute shadows using the 10th and 90th percentiles and the quantile method of type 6. Usage:

   ```
   ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt)) + 
       geom_point() +
       stat_shadows(stat = "quartile")
   ```

[image]

Unfortunately, my lack of familiarity with extending `ggplot2` stopped me well short of my objective. These plots were "faked" with `geom_segment`. Based on the tutorial and discussions cited above and inspecting existing code like `stat-qq` or `stat-smooth`, I have put together a basic architecture for this goal. It must contain many mistakes, I would be grateful for guidance. Also, note that either of these approaches would be fine: `geom_shadows(anchor = c(35, 1))` or `geom_shadows(x = 35, y = 1)`.

Now here are my efforts. First, `geom-shadows.r` to define `geom_shadows()`. Second, `stat-shadows.r` to define `stat_shadows()`. The code doesn't work as is. But if I execute its content, it does produce the desired statistics. For clarity, I have removed most of the calculations in `stat_shadows()`, such as quartiles, to focus on essentials. Any obvious mistake in the layout?

**geom-shadows.r**

```
#' documentation ought to be here
geom_shadows <- function(
  mapping = NULL, 
  data = NULL, 
  stat = "shadows", 
  position = "identity", 
  ...,
  anchor = list(x = 0, y = 0),
  shadows = list("x", "y"), 
  type = NULL,
  na.rm = FALSE,
  show.legend = NA, 
  inherit.aes = TRUE) {
    layer(
      data = data,
      mapping = mapping,
      stat = stat,
      geom = GeomShadows,
      position = position,
      show.legend = show.legend,
      inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
      params = list(
        anchor = anchor,
        shadows = shadows,
        type = type,  
        na.rm = na.rm,
        ...
    )
  )
}

GeomShadows <- ggproto("GeomShadows", Geom, 

  # set up the data, e.g. remove missing data
  setup_data = function(data, params) { 
    data 
  }, 

  # set up the parameters, e.g. supply warnings for incorrect input
  setup_params = function(data, params) {
    params
  },

  draw_group = function(data, panel_params, coord, anchor, shadows, type) { 
    # draw_group uses stats returned by compute_group

    # set common aesthetics
    geom_aes <- list(
      alpha = data$alpha,
      colour = data$color,
      size = data$size,
      linetype = data$linetype,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha),
      group = data$group
    )

    # merge aesthetics with data calculated in setup_data
    geom_stats <- new_data_frame(c(list(
          x = c(data$x.xmin, data$y.xmin),
          xend = c(data$x.xmax, data$y.xmax),
          y = c(data$x.ymin, data$y.ymin),
          yend = c(data$x.ymax, data$y.ymax),
          alpha = c(data$alpha, data$alpha) 
        ), geom_aes
      ), n = 2) 

    # turn the stats data into a GeomPath
    geom_grob <- GeomSegment$draw_panel(unique(geom_stats), 
        panel_params, coord) 

    # pass the GeomPath to grobTree
    ggname("geom_shadows", grobTree(geom_grob)) 
  },

  # set legend box styles
  draw_key = draw_key_path,

  # set default aesthetics 
  default_aes = aes(
    colour = "blue",
    fill = "red",
    size = 1,
    linetype = 1,
    alpha = 1
  )

)
```

**stat-shadows.r**

```
#' documentation ought to be here
stat_shadows <-  
  function(mapping = NULL, 
           data = NULL,
           geom = "shadows", 
           position = "identity",
           ...,
           # do I need to add the geom_shadows arguments here?
           anchor = list(x = 0, y = 0),
           shadows = list("x", "y"), 
           type = NULL,
           na.rm = FALSE,
           show.legend = NA,
           inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    stat = StatShadows,  
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    geom = geom,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(
      # geom_shadows argument repeated here?
      anchor = anchor,  
      shadows = shadows,
      type = type,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

StatShadows <- 
  ggproto("StatShadows", Stat,

    # do I need to repeat required_aes?
    required_aes = c("x", "y"), 

    # set up the data, e.g. remove missing data
    setup_data = function(data, params) {
      data
    },

    # set up parameters, e.g. unpack from list
    setup_params = function(data, params) {
      params
    },

    # calculate shadows: returns data_frame with colnames: xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax 
    compute_group = function(data, scales, anchor = list(x = 0, y = 0), shadows = list("x", "y"), type = NULL, na.rm = TRUE) {

      .compute_shadows(data = data, anchor = anchor, shadows = shadows, type = type)

  }
)

# Calculate the shadows for each type / shadows / anchor
.compute_shadows <- function(data, anchor, shadows, type) {

# Deleted all type-checking, etc. for MWE
# Only 'type = c(double, double)' accepted, e.g. type = c(0, 1)

qs <- type

# compute shadows along the x-axis
if (any(shadows == "x")) {
    shadows.x <- c(
    xmin = as.numeric(stats::quantile(data[, "x"], qs[[1]])),
    xmax = as.numeric(stats::quantile(data[, "x"], qs[[2]])),
    ymin = anchor[["y"]], 
    ymax = anchor[["y"]]) 
}

# compute shadows along the y-axis
if (any(shadows == "y")) {
    shadows.y <- c(
    xmin = anchor[["x"]], 
    xmax = anchor[["x"]], 
    ymin = as.numeric(stats::quantile(data[, "y"], qs[[1]])),
    ymax = as.numeric(stats::quantile(data[, "y"], qs[[2]])))
} 

# store shadows in one data_frame
stats <- new_data_frame(c(x = shadows.x, y = shadows.y))

# return the statistics
stats
}

.
```

Comment: This question was edited to reflect the most important issues: In particular, I have fixed obvious problems in ``draw_group`` when merging the aesthetics with the data. The code is mostly based on ``geom_boxplot`` and ``stat_boxplot``, particularly the ``whiskers``.

Comment: Note that for the code above to compile, you either need to prefix special functions with ``ggplot2::`` and copy functions like ``new_data_frame`` or (which is what I do) clone the ``ggplot2`` package and compile it with the above two files added and properly referenced in ``NAMESPACE`` and ``DESCRIPTION``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until a more thorough answer comes along: You are missing

```
extra_params = c("na.rm", "shadows", "anchor", "type"),
```

inside `GeomShadows <- ggproto("GeomShadows", Geom,`

and possibly also inside `StatShadows <- ggproto("StatShadows", Stat,`.

Inside `geom-.r` and `stat-.r` there are many very useful comments that clarify how geoms and stats work. In particular (hat tips Claus Wilke over at github issues):

```
# Most parameters for the geom are taken automatically from draw_panel() or
# draw_groups(). However, some additional parameters may be needed
# for setup_data() or handle_na(). These can not be imputed automatically,
# so the slightly hacky "extra_params" field is used instead. By
# default it contains `na.rm`
extra_params = c("na.rm"),
```